# How my bullet can take HP from enemy?

Tags: unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform barrel;
    public float range = 0f;
    public Rigidbody myBullet;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Rigidbody bulletInstance; // reference
            //make the bullet apear out of the barrel
            bulletInstance = Instantiate(myBullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            bulletInstance.AddForce(barrel.forward * range); //give the bullet some force to move forward
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Fire()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(barrel.position, transform.forward);
        // in don't know how write this iff
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, range))
        {
            Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
            enemy.health -= 1;
        }
        //Debug.DrawRay(barrel.position, transform.forward * range);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I made an enemy class, my bullet is a prefab, but i don't understand what i need to do to lower HP points when the bullet hits.

Comment: you could use colliders to remove HP when bullet reaches a target enemy

Comment: thx, i understand these, but can u give me an example pls?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have 2 halves to 2 different solutions for this, so I'll explain both possible solutions and let you choose the one that best suites your needs

**Solution 1**
*Initiate a bullet instance and remove the health from enemies the bullet hits*

In your GunScript fire a bullet when the mouse button is down (this is half the code you already have)

```
public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour {
   public Transform barrel;
   public float range = 0f;
   public GameObject myBullet;

   void Update()
   {
       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       {
           Rigidbody bulletInstance; // reference
           //make the bullet apear out of the barrel
           bulletInstance = Instantiate(myBullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation) as GameObject;
           //give the bullet some force to move forward
           bulletInstance.GetComponent<RigidBody>().AddForce(barrel.forward * range);
       }
   }
}
```

Then, on your bullet pref you would [detect collisions](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) and remove health from your enemy class:

```
public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour {
   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
   {
       Enemy enemy = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();

       // If we hit an enemy, then reduce it's health
       if (enemy != null)
       {
           enemy.health -= 1;
       }

       // Remove the bullet from the scene, we don't need it any more
       Destroy(gameObject);
   }
}
```

Note that this approach is innefficient, as you're creating a new bullet for each shot fired. This may not be a problem for your game, but if, for example, your gun was a machine gun you'll find that your games performance will suffer as a result. If you need to show bullets, then I'd recomend an [object pool](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7877/how-do-you-use-a-pool-of-objects-rather-than-creat.html)

**Solution 2**
*Cast a ray for each bullet fired and remove enemy health if the ray hits*

In your GunScript, calculate a ray hit when the mouse button is down (this is the other half of the code you already have). No need for the Enumerable, or the Bullet prefab here. All the code is in the GunScript

```
public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour {
   public Transform barrel;
   public float range = 0f;

   void Update()
   {
       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
       {
           RaycastHit hit;
           if (Physics.Raycast(barrel.position, transform.forward, out hit, range))
           {
               Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
               // Only take health if an enemy was hit
               if (enemy != null) {
                   enemy.health -= 1;
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Note that with this approach you don't get a bullet flying across the screen, but that might be fine for your purposes, as you can mask this by just showing a muzzle flash and playing a gun sound. However, because the Raycast is efficient, and you're not instantiating and destroying multiple game objects, this approach is more suitable for firing multiple bullets in quick succession

Comment: why use physics though and not OnCollisionEnter(Collider collider) and then just detect who the bullet was hitting and fetch his health component or whats holding that and reduce health (physics computation especially raycasting is pricey).

Comment: A raycast will mean you're not spawning an object per shot (which can lead to the garbage collector freezing the game briefly, if you don't use an object pool), and will also mean that you're guarenteed to score a hit, which may mot be true of collision detection unless you use 'Continuous' detection mode (which again, can be pricey if you have a lot of bullets). As there isn't a one-size fits all solution to this problem (as both have pros and cons), and the OP had already shown parts of 2 different approaches I thought it best to give both possibilities for consideration :-)

Comment: I don't think raycasting is more costly than OnCollisionEnter (which is itself a physics computation and will rely on all the same structures a raycast would likely be using). If anything, it is less costly over time since it is only calculated once as opposed to collision detection which will have to be performed for the lifetime of the bullet. That said, while a raycast might never yield a false negative as hobnob suggests, that doesn't necessarily behave realistically or as the OP intends since bullets do in fact travel in real life.